# Store a const reference, whenever an lvalue is passed, and a copy, whenever an rvalue is passed

Tags: c++, c++14, rvalue-reference, type-traits

Please consider the following code:

```
template<typename T>
class scalar_reference
{
public:
    template<typename U>
    scalar_reference(U&& value)
        : m_value(std::forward<U>(value))
    {}

    T const& operator()() const { return m_value; }

private:
    T m_value;
};

template<typename T>
scalar_reference<T> foo(T&& value) {
    return scalar_reference<T>{ std::forward<T>(value) };
}
```

The intention is that the `scalar_reference` returned by `foo` holds a const reference to a `std::decay_t<T>` whenever `foo` is invoked with an lvalue and a copy whenver `foo` is invoked with an rvalue.

The above code doesn't work. For example, if we call `int x; foo(x)`, `T` will be `int&` and hence `operator()` will return `int&` too (since the `const` qualifier has no effect on a reference type).

So, how do we need to change the code?

Comment: Why not just declare two constructors; one taking an lvalue reference, and one an rvalue reference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the only problem the return type of `operator()`? If so, you can just drop the reference first:

```
std::decay_t<T> const& operator()() const { return m_value; }
```

Comment: Yeah, you might be right. I didn't noticed that this actually is the only problem.